# How to insert a line break every 5 values?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, document.write

Recently, I have to write a program which, when I have received 5 values in my `document.write`, the program has to start on a new line.
I searched on multiple things on the internet and I found nothing about it. Here I show you how to deal with it. Hope it can help you!

```
var countr = 0;
for(i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    document.write(i+" ");
    compteur++;
    if (count === 5) {
        document.write("<br>");
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is. Have you solved the problem and you're showing us your solution? Or your solution doesn't work and you want help? The code presented has three different spellings for what I presume is meant to be the same variable (`countr`, `compteur`, `count`).

Comment: If you have solved the issue and wish to share it, ask a question in the question box, then share your solution as an answer.

Comment: Your code have some issues like countr variable as pointed and the is statement.
Try this `if (countr % 5 === 0)` and make the countr to be used everywhere

Answer (score 3):

You want to use i % 5 === 0 -- Modulus will calculate the remainder. Use in an if statement to write `<br>` when it returns 0.

```
//var countr = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
  document.write(i + " ");
  // compteur++;
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    document.write("<br>");
    // count =0;
  }
}
```

Since you're using a loop, you can use `i` in your comparison as long as you don't update the variable. You're also using countr, compteur, count while you can use `i` instead. // comments (disables) code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what result you are expecting. But at first what I see - you have written your counter incorrect 3 times.

```
var counter= 0;
for(i=1 ; i<=50 ;i++){
    document.write(i+" ");
    counter++;
    if (counter === 5){
        document.write("<br>");
        counter =0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only write <br> once on counter === 5